# How to boot XNU kernel?

Tags: macos, system, darwin, xnu

I have compiled XNU 3789.31.2 from source successfully but don't know how to boot it and get it run.
Is there any detailed instruction for that?

Comment: This is an interesting question. Have you looked into a book called Linux From Scratch? I know, I know, this is for linux. *But*, as far as booting is concerned, some aspects of the book may give you a few hints on how to make almost any kernel bootable. I apologize if my comment is not helpful at all.

Comment: Here's how to create a partition: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter02/creatingpartition.html

Comment: Here's the compilation steps for compiling Linux from inside the new partition: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter08/kernel.html

Comment: Although, probably, you're using something other than grub, but, it should give you an idea about how to work with a bootloader: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter08/grub.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of an up to date standalone Darwin OS build; the main way to run a recent xnu build is therefore to use it to boot regular OS X/macOS.